# How I can decrease size of vendor.js in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I deploy my project in my server, every time I load the page I see that the file `vendor.js` take 34 s to load and its size is 12Mb, I don't know how to reduce or minify it because I don't find it in my project.
I'm a beginner in angular sorry it is a basic question

I try `ng build --prod` because I found it in a question but I don't get any result

Answer (score 2):

Decrease number of used external libraries

Comment: Simple and on point. Btw, these libraries are found in _package.json_ under "dependencies".